# How to add Kafka dependencies for PySpark on a Jupyter notebook

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, jupyter, spark-kafka-integration

I have setup kafka 2.1 on windows and able to successfully communicate a topic from producer to consumer over localhost:9092.

I now want to consume this in a spark structured stream.

For this I setup spark 3.4 and installed pyspark over Jupyter kernel and its working well.

The issue I have now is with how to correctly configure the Kafka spark dependency jars on Jupyter. I have tried the following:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("KafkaStreamingExample") \
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0') \
    .getOrCreate()

stream_df = spark.readStream\
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "stocky") \
    .load()
```

I get the error

> Failed to find data source: kafka

I know there are options to load the packages with spark-submit, but I particularly need to know if its possible to get it working within the Jupyter notebook environment.

It would be great if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is correct, but version matters. You're running Spark 3.4.0? So you'll be unable to use spark-sql-kafka-0-10 version **3.3.0**

You also need the Kafka client JAR for using with pyspark

https://github.com/OneCricketeer/docker-stacks/blob/master/hadoop-spark/spark-notebooks/kafka-sql.ipynb

Comment: Thanks for that,

I had updated my code with what I believe is the correct version as follows:

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("KafkaStreamingExample") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13:3.4.0,org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.4.0") \
    .getOrCreate()

however, it is still failing to find the kafka source. Is there some additional confis required ?

Comment: Make sure the Scala version is correct as well. `2.12` vs `2.13` part of the package name. You'll find this listed in other JARs that are part of the Spark classpath

Comment: Thanks, I heard from the grapevine that the more recent versions of PySpark does not work well with the kafka driver 0.10. So to be on the safe side I dropped way back to the earlier version spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.4 and downgrading my PySpark to 2.3.4. And now its working as expected. Its quite possible a couple of versions higher may also work, but for the moment I am happy. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Spark 3+ would definitely be recommended over a 4+ year old version... I've not personally had issues with it